# Rendering a shiny datatable with a caption/title and pre-selected rows

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

I'm trying to code a `shiny app` for plotting `xy` data. Each `xy` point is associated with several factors:

```
set.seed(1)
data.df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000), y = rnorm(1000),
                      sex = sample(c("F", "M"), 1000, replace = T),
                      age = sample(c("Y", "O"), 1000, replace = T),
                      group = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 1000, replace = T),
                      stringsAsFactors = F)

design.df <- data.frame(factor.name = c(c(rep("sex",2), rep("age",2), rep("group",4))),
                        factor.levels = c("F", "M","Y", "O","A", "B", "C", "D"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would like to enable the user to subset the `xy` data (`data.df`) based on a selection of multiple rows from `design.df` using `DT::renderDT` within `renderUI` in the `server`, where the default selection is all rows of `design.df`. This works fine using this code:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(shiny))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(DT))

server <- function(input, output)
{
  output$design.idx <- renderUI({
    output$design.df <- DT::renderDT(design.df, server = TRUE, selection = list(mode = "multiple", selected = rownames(design.df)[1:nrow(design.df)]))
    DT::dataTableOutput("design.df")
  })

  xy.plot <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$design.df_rows_selected)){
      selected.design.df <- design.df[input$design.df_rows_selected,,drop = FALSE]
      selected.idx <- lapply(unique(selected.design.df$factor.name), function(f) which(data.df[,f] %in% dplyr::filter(selected.design.df, factor.name == f)$factor.levels)) %>%
        unlist() %>% unique()
      plot.df <- data.df[selected.idx,,drop=F]
      xy.plot <- suppressWarnings(plotly::plot_ly(marker = list(size = 3), type = 'scatter', mode = "markers", x = plot.df$x, y = plot.df$y, showlegend = FALSE) %>%
                                            plotly::layout(xaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE), yaxis = list(zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE, showgrid = FALSE)))
    } else{
      xy.plot <- NULL
    }
    return(xy.plot)
  })

  output$outPlot <- plotly::renderPlotly({
    xy.plot()
  })
}


ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Results Explorer"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      uiOutput("design.idx")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotly::plotlyOutput("outPlot")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

But I would also like to have a title or caption for the rendered `datatable`, so I tried replacing:

```
output$design.df <- DT::renderDT(design.df, server = TRUE, selection = list(mode = "multiple", selected = rownames(design.df)[1:nrow(design.df)]))
```

with:

```
output$design.df <- DT::renderDT(datatable(design.df, caption = "Subset Selection"), server = TRUE, selection = list(mode = "multiple", selected = rownames(design.df)[1:nrow(design.df)]))
```

in which case the `selected = rownames(design.df)[1:nrow(design.df)]` argument seems to be ignored and the default selection is no rows.
Changing `selected = rownames(design.df)[1:nrow(design.df)]` to `selected = 1:nrow(design.df)` makes no difference.

Any idea how to get both a title or caption to the rendered table together with have all rows as a pre-selection default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put selection in the `datatable` object:

```
output$design.df <- DT::renderDT(
    datatable(design.df, 
        caption = "Subset Selection",  
        selection = list(mode = "multiple",  
                         selected = rownames(design.df)[1:nrow(design.df)])
        ), 
    server = TRUE)
```